# JQuery Form No reload : how to pass the $_POST info after success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

First the code below works, but truth be told i don't know why :) it just worked after many trial and errors

I need the $_POST data submitted through the #filter-form, for loading the page as action1 function will require $_POST data.

If i remove +data or .html(data) it doesn't work anymore.
Also if i change url:"..." it does not work anymore either and i don't understand why as i don't need to to anything here, all i need is to load this page.php page and pass the $_POST so that it can output properly.

My QUESTION is, WHY does it work ? (i want to understand why putting +data or html(data) is so important to make sure $_POST is passed) and how can i make it more proper ?
Thanks for your help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#filter-form").submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/page.php?action=action1",
                //Specify the datatype of response if necessary
                data: $("#filter-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                        alert("succeess");
                        $("#tableresult").load("includes/page.php?action=action1"+data).html(data);
                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            </script>';
```

Comment: You really seem to needing this -> https://learn.jquery.com/ and most definitively this -> https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `.load()` at all. It should be:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    $("#tableresult").html(data);
}
```

This takes the response that the AJAX server returned, which should be HTML code, and puts it into the `tableresult` element.

The way you had it written, you're calling the server twice, which doesn't seem right.